# Nesting functions in Knockout looks messy, why not use prototype key word?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How is:

```
var ViewModel = function() {}
var ViewModel.prototype.functionName = function() {};
```

different from:

```
var ViewModel = function() {

    this.functionName = function() { ... }
}
```

And would the first approach be considered "wrong"? To me it seems much more readable then the second. I believe the second is the first, just with out the concept of "writing `.prototype.` every time"?

Any help clearing this up might make things make more sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is where the function is defined.

Using the `ViewModel.prototype.functionName` version, the function is defined in the prototype and is available to all instances of the type without further execution cost or memory consumption.

Using `this.functionName`, the function is defined in the instance itself. It has the advantage of allowing every instance to have a unique version of the function, usually used to capture instance specific data.

Comment: Is this explained on the site any where? There docs seem to be lacking this explanation.

Comment: The only site there is the knock out site. the only docs there are, the knockout docs. Why is this not explained?

Comment: @KyleAdams - because this has nothing to do with Knockout. These are core JavaScript concepts you should familiarize yourself with. Knockout is a JavaScript based library, you need to know the underlying fundamentals first.

Comment: cool, im pretty familiar with JS. Just not with these concepts of nesting functions in functions. it looks messy and looks like itll be hard to maintain the future, ill go back to react where its cleaner.